# Postgres: Can I create an index to use in the SELECT clause?

Tags: postgresql, select, indexing

I have defined a function that determines the timezone from table tz_world for a set of lon, lat values:

```
create function get_timezone(numeric, numeric) 
  returns character varying(30) as $$
    select tzid from tz_world where ST_Contains(geom, ST_MakePoint($1, $2)); 
$$ language SQL immutable;
```

Now I would like to use this function in the SELECT clause of a query on a different table:

```
select get_timezone(lon, lat) from event where...;
```

The function is rather slow, so I tried using an index to speed things up:

```
create index event_timezone_idx on event (get_timezone(event.lon, event.lat));
```

While this speeds up queries where the function is used in the WHERE clause, it has no effect on the variant above where get_timezone(lon, lat) is used in the SELECT clause.

Is it possible to rephrase the query and/or index to speed up the timezone determination?

**Update** 
Thank you for the answers!! I decided to include an extra column for the timezone in the end and populate it when creating/updating the events.

Comment: When you use the function in the `select` list, there is no way to speed that up because Postgres needs to run the function for every row that is returned

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a local temporary table of the part of the select where you want to create the index on and then create an index on the temporary one:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS (
select
.
.
.
);
CREATE INDEX temp_table idx
  ON temp_table 
  USING btree
  (col1,col2,....);
```

Otherwise write what you want your WHERE condition to be, indexes only work on WHERE clauses and values for the index should be exactly the ones you are trying to filter on.